# mysql query with date hours and interval

Tags: mysql

I have EXPIRATION column in mysql table which contains date in following format

2022-02-15 08:00:00

I am trying to query username whose expiry is on 2022-02-17 08:00:00 using below query

SELECT username FROM users WHERE expiration = DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);

but getting no result. is something wrong with my query?

Comment: CURDATE() returns date component only, with zero timepart. So your query searches only the rows which' expiration timepoint is the midnight (00:00:00) strictly. Either cut off the timepart from expiration column value or use unequiation.

Comment: can u please provide a exampel CMd for it?

Comment: Smells like you are in Pacific time and mixing DATETIMEs and TIMESTAMPs?  Let's talk about cleaning up the data before talking about date arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

Your request will return the `username` of your `users` tables which have an `expiration` strictly equal to the `DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

Changing `=` for `<` should help getting more results.

`SELECT username FROM users WHERE expiration < DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);`

Comment: Do not even breathe "curdate() + 1" -- It computes incorrectly!

Comment: Can't tell if you're taking this computation literally, but this was an illustration. Maybe the code block was misleading, sorry for that. I thought my last block (with full query was clear enough), thank you for highlighting this.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it.  "+1" works some of the time and it could lead users into bugs that are hard to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT username FROM users WHERE expiration = DATE_ADD(curdate(),
> INTERVAL 1 DAY);

```
SELECT username 
FROM users 
WHERE DATE(expiration) = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

If today is '2023-12-21' this will fetch users with expiration as '2023-12-22 18:30:10' and '2023-12-22 00:00:00'.

Assuming expirations are generally based on date only (not including the time component).